# Prefer id attribute or data attribute in page with many elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a HTML page with many, many "widgets" (can be in the magnitude of 1000, many not visible by `display:none` which get's modified dynamically by user interaction).
Each widget must carry some information regarding it.

At the moment I'm building that DOM piece by piece and add a jQuery `.data()` to each widget. But this building of little blocks is too slow (lots of time spent in Parse HTML), so I want to switch to a new approach where I first build a string of all widgets and then add that to the DOM with `innerHTML` at one go. But this doesn't allow me to use the `.data()` during the build anymore.

As all widgets have a unique ID anyway (currently only stored in the `.data()`...) I could think of two obvious solutions:

1. Give every widget an `id` attribute with the widget ID as content
2. Give every widget an `data-widgetid` attribute with the ID as content

(Parallel to that I'd have a big JavaScript hash that links the widget-id to the per widget data.)

What approach should I prefer?

Performance and resources is an issue (also on mobile devices).
By the `id` attribute I'm interfering with the DOM, so I don't know if that could have any negative effects. (E.g. it could be that browsers are starting to build an extra look up structure for that internally that I could avoid otherwise. I'm not a browser developer, so I don't know if that is the case though)

Comment: If possible , can post `html` , `js` ?

Comment: Yes, but it looks boring :) In the past I used `var w = $('<div class="widget">...</div>'); w.data({...}); upperElement.append(w);`. And now it could look like: Option 1.: `<div class="widget" id="my_id">...</div>` and option 2.: `<div class="widget" data-widgetid="my_id">...</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to get those elements by their `id`, and you will only use it to associate data with the elements, I would recommend not using `id`.

Since `id`s are unique, browsers build a hash table to retrieve elements by `id` so fast.

Therefore, adding `id`s to lots of elements that don't need them will increase the size of the hash table unnecessarily.

In average, a search in a hash table is `O(1)`, so the size doesn't matter. However, on the worst case, it's `O(n)`, so better have a small table if you can.

This way, if you use `document.getElementById` to get other elements, it may be faster.

Comment: That's basically what I had in mind - without the ability to express it like that :)

Answer (score 4):

Use ID. If you want to protect the ID namespace of the DOM, use a prefix. For example, , where "123" is the unique ID. If your application is driven by a database, the primary key conveniently provides non-colliding ID values. Otherwise use a client-side counter to generate unique IDs.

Accessing the element by ID is much faster via document.getElementById. Modern browsers allow this kind of access really fast. The internal storage is also more efficient comparing to a custom attribute. To access a custom attribute, you'll have to traverse all the matching nodes and compare them with the values of the custom attribute. Some old IE also don't support custom attributes.

Comment: You are assuming that I want to access widgets by the widget-id. But that's not the case (otherwise the `id` attribute would be an obvious choice). Apart from that I can follow you.